# Clear prefixes for specific map in mapping profile only

Tags: automapper

Is there a way to use ClearPrefixes() within a mapping profile for a specific CreateMap() call only?

I have a mapping profile with lots of CreateMaps() calls. For just one of these mappings I need to turn off automatic recognition of Get* prefixes since this maps also to the wrong property in my case: In source class I have Source.GetProp as a bool property and in target class I have Target.GetProp as a bool property and Target.Prop as a string property. AutoMapper also writes "true" or "false" string into Prop - which seems to be expected behaviour.

It would be very hard to look into all classes for side effects if I turn on ClearPrefixes() globally. Hence I would rather just clear prefixes for this single mapping.

At the moment I excluded this single property by calling Ignore() on its map. But it would be nice to clear prefixes for this map entirely since there might be more properties in the future with the same naming convention so I will always have to keep that in mind.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do that is to move that particular map in its own profile.

That should work, profiles are just logical groupings. In the end, all maps are global.

Comment: Nice workaround - thanks! Didn't know you can define multiple profiles.

Comment: You should mark it as an answer, prefixes are per profile, not per map, so this is as good as it gets.